# Does taking partial trace commute with local operators?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-information, density-operator

Suppose we have a big system with two subsystems $H=A\otimes B$. For a unitary $U$ in the Hilbert space $A$ and a state $\rho$ in the Hilbert space $H$. Is the following statement true?
$$ \text{Tr}_B [U\otimes \mathbb{1}_A \rho (U\otimes \mathbb{1}_A)^\dagger] = U \text{Tr}_B(\rho) U^\dagger$$

Physically it feels quite convincing because someone doing experiments in his lab $A$ should not be concerned about the word outside ($B$). But mathematically, this statements seems nontrivial to me.

Comment: The physical intuition you expressed seems misplaced to me because it can be true only if there exists a wavefunction for subsystem $B$. A wavefunction $\rho$ in full Hilbert space $H$ doesn't necessarily imply a wavefunction for $B$ as $\rho$ can be an entangled state.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I tried with random numerical examples and it seems to be true.

Comment: @DvijMankad Thanks for you comment. I think here $\rho$ means (reduced) density matrix, which always exists.

Comment: Did you try to use the formula for the partial trace?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Einstein's summation convention for repeated indices,
$$[(U\otimes\mathbb 1)\rho(U^\dagger\otimes \mathbb 1)]_{ijkl}
= U_{im} \delta_{jn}\rho_{mnpq} U^*_{kp}\delta_{lq}
=U_{im}U^*_{kp}\rho_{mjpl}$$

$$(\operatorname{Tr}_B[(U\otimes\mathbb 1)\rho(U^\dagger\otimes \mathbb 1)])_{ik}
=[(U\otimes\mathbb 1)\rho(U^\dagger\otimes \mathbb 1)]_{ijkj}
= U_{im}U^*_{kp}\rho_{mjpj}
= U_{im}U^*_{kp}\operatorname{Tr}_B(\rho)_{mp}
= (U\operatorname{Tr}_B(\rho)U^\dagger)_{ik}$$